# Triggering a win function in Hangman

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm quite new to coding and I have started coding a hangman game for a school project. Currently I'm having issues relating to triggering a win. I'm also having another issue where it is printing none after user input. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
print ("WELCOME, YOU ARE PLAYING HANGMAN!")

import random
def guess():

    word = (random.choice(open("Level1py.txt").readline().split()))
    guesses = 8

#If letterguessed == current letter in word, add that letter else add a _

#guess function
guessword = []
word = (random.choice(open("Level1py.txt").readline().split()))
guesses = 8
def checkLetter(letter, word, guess_word):
for c in word:
    if c == letter:
        guess_word[word.index(c)] = c
        word_list = list(word)
        word_list[word.index(c)] = "*"
        word = ''.join(word_list)
        print(guess_word)
guess_word = ['_' for x in word]
while '_' in guess_word:
guess = input('Letter: ')
print(checkLetter(guess, word, guess_word))
while guesses > -1 and not guess_word == word:
            guess = input("Guess:")
            if guess in word:
                    print("correct letter")
                    print(guess_word)
            else:
                    print("incorrect")
                    guesses -= 1
            if guesses < 0:
                        print ("""
_______
|/   |    
|   (_)    
|   /|\          
|    |        
|   / \        
|              
|___          
HANGMAN""""You guessed wrong. The correct word was: " + str(word))
            else:
                    print("congrats, you won")
```

Comment: What issue are you having, specifically?

Comment: 1. Its not triggering any kind of win once i have guessed all of the correct letters. I know I am doing something completely wrong and could use some help. 2. Program is printing "none" after each user input

Comment: What should I add?

Comment: The code for the win is inside the loop that terminates if a win is detected. So, it will never get run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really need to review your indentation and simplify your code. The reason that a win is never triggered is that the else statement is never reached (due to the not `guess_word == word` condition in the while loop). You need to take the end of the game out of the while loop. You're also unnecessarily printing `guess_word` in several places.

Here's a working version. You can test it here: https://repl.it/@glhr/hangman. I hard-coded the word instead of taking it from a file since that part was irrelevant to your problem.

```
print ("WELCOME, YOU ARE PLAYING HANGMAN!")

guessword = []
word = "test"
guesses = 8
guess_word = ['_' for x in word]
def checkLetter(letter, word, guess_word):
    for c in word:
            if c == letter:
                    guess_word[word.index(c)] = c
                    print(guess_word)

while '_' in guess_word and guesses > -1:
    guess = input('Letter: ')

    if guess in word:
                    print("correct letter")
    else:
                    print("incorrect")
                    guesses -= 1
                    print (guesses," guesses left")
    checkLetter(guess, word, guess_word)

if guesses < 0:
    print ("""
    |/   |    
    |   (_)    
    |   /|\          
    |    |        
    |   / \        
    |              
    |___          
    HANGMAN"""" You guessed wrong. The correct word was: " + str(word))
else:
    print("congrats, you won")
```

Comment: Glad I could help. Also, the reason why your code was printing `None` is because of this line: `print(checkLetter(guess, word, guess_word))` You were trying to print the output of the `checkLetter` function but that function does not return any value, so there is nothing to print.